# cannot convert ‘void (myClass::*)() to void (*)()

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

So, I know this question exists in so many places. But none of the examples helped me solve my issue.

I'm trying to create a **method pointer** (within a class), so it will address one of several methods of the class according to specific conditions.

I tried, unsuccessfully to use a static function (guess I misunderstood the instructions how to do so...).

here is the header file:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int value);

    void methodA(const string &msg);
    void methodB(const string &msg);

    void (*send_msg)(const string &msg);
};
```

and the cpp:

```
myClass::myClass(int value){
    if(value > 0){
        send_msg = &methodA
    }
    else{
        send_msg = &methodB
    }
}
```

and the errors, as some of you already know:

> error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&myClass::methodA’ [-fpermissive]
>
> error: cannot convert ‘void (myClass::*)(const string&) {aka void (myClass::*)(const std::basic_string&)}’ to ‘void (*)(const string&) {aka void (*)(const std::basic_string&)}’ in assignment

any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit**
Thanks to Jose, it can be compile:

```
void (myClass::*send_msg)(const string &msg);
```

and the assignment:

```
send_msg = &myClass::methodA;
```

But now, as I'm trying to use the code I cannot call the function-pointer:

```
this->myClass_instance.send_msg(line); //*****getting error*****
```

when `this` is an instance of other class.
The error is:

> error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘((otherClass*)this)->otherClass::myClass_instance.myClass::send_msg (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* ((otherClass*)this)->otherClass::myClass_instance.myClass::send_msg) (...)’

Comment: ammm.. wouldn't it be easier, more readable and shorter using `std::function` and a lambda function?

Comment: @DavidHaim Ill be glad to see an example

Comment: How do you intend on using `send_msg`?

Comment: According to your edit, `methodA` and `methodB` should be static member functions.

Comment: Maybe it's not what you want (perhaps in real life your code is way more complex than this) but I can't help think that this is a very complicated way to solve a simple problem. Wouldn't derived class with pure virtual function and a factory method, for example, give you a more maintainable and easier to use solution? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My demo: http://ideone.com/Vx4x88

Make send_msg a pointer to a class method by adding `myClass::`.

```
void (myClass::*send_msg)(const string &msg);
```

Also, it seems like you are missing `myClass::` and a semicolon `;` at the end of

```
    send_msg = &myClass::methodA;
else
    send_msg = &myClass::methodB;
```

Edit:

Since your requested how to call it from outside the class in your comment:

```
myClass c(1);
(c.*c.send_msg)("hi");
```

or

```
myClass * p = new myClass(1);
(p->*p->send_msg)("hi");
```

Comment: @Jose Thanks. It seem to be compile, but I'm getting `error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘myClass’` when tring to call it from outside.

Comment: @Eli So how did you call it?

Comment: @Eli Check this http://ideone.com/Vx4x88 and work from there. It has a working example of what you are trying to do (plus i've added a new function called "method" that can be called from outside far more easily); Scroll down in the ideone example and check the output.

Comment: The thing with `(c.*c.send_msg)("Hi");` is unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

`void (*send_msg)(const string &msg);` is declaration of pointer for free function or static member function, not non-static member function. You might want:

```
void (myClass::*send_msg)(const string &msg);
```

[LIVE1](http://rextester.com/TDEPXG81273)

Or you could make the functions to be static member function:

```
static void methodA(const string &msg);
static void methodB(const string &msg);
```

[LIVE2](http://rextester.com/RGQOE58369)

For the 1st compile error, you should qualify name of non-static member function when taking its address (for the 1st solution only):

```
myClass::myClass(int value){
    if(value > 0){
        send_msg = &myClass::methodA;
                    ~~~~~~~~~
    }
    else{
        send_msg = &myClass::methodB;
                    ~~~~~~~~~
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `std::function`

```
#include <functional>

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int value){
     if(value > 0){
        send_msg = [this](const std::string& str){ methodA(str); };
     }
     else{
         send_msg = [this](const std::string& str){ methodB(str); };
     }
    }

    void methodA(const string &msg);
    void methodB(const string &msg);

    std::function<void(const string &msg)> send_msg;
};
```

to call the function, simply use `()` :

```
myClass obj(10);
obj.send_msg("hi there");
```

Comment: But I think the question was about member function pointers, and it's really important to know how to do those, and not go for the easiest path which is std::function. Mainly, because it has a lot of overheads, like memory allocation, virtual call, and even an empty std::function object itself is usually really big (40 bytes at least in MSVC2015).

Comment: I'm tend to go with the minimum overheads. Didn't checked it, but I'm hope Jose solution will be better. +1 for both answers.

Comment: I agree it's not 100% precent equivilant to member functions, I wanted to show an alternative approach. anyway, although the cons are real should be taken seriously, the pros are that `std::function` is easier and safer, as it can't be null or dangle. an empty `std::function` will throw an exception when invoked, while calling nulled/dangling member function will have UB

Comment: `std::function` is easier, I agree, but you can have a reference to a member function pointer and then it can't dangle. Ie: `const decltype(&methodA)& send_msg;` (and you can assign it in the member initializer list). And only a 4 byte overhead.